# Check for empty input Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to implement a demo contact form with javascript so that if any input is empty, the custom error message is triggered for each input.

Key part of the html code (sorry if the reading is heavy):

```
<form action="/contact.php" method="POST" id="contact--form" onsubmit="return contactFormEmpty()" name="contact--form"></form>
 <input class="form--input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="CORREO ELECTRONICO"><br>
 <p id="contact--form--email--error" class="contact--form--error">Error: no se ha entrado ningun correo</p>

 <input class="form--input" type="text" name="nombre" id="name" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
 <p id="contact--form--name--error" class="contact--form--error">Error: no se ha entrado ningun nombre</p>

 <input class="form--input" type="text" name="surrname" id="surrname" placeholder="APELLIDO"><br>

 <input class="form--input form--problem--info" type="text" name="info" id="info" placeholder="DESCRIBE TU PROBLEMA"><br>
 <p id="contact--form--info--error" class="contact--form--error">Error: no se ha descrito el problema.</p>

 <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR INFORMACIÓN" form="contact--form">

</form>
```

CSS code :

```
.contact--form--error {
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript code :

```
function contactFormEmpty() {
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value; email.trim();
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value; name.trim();
    if(email=="") {
        document.getElementById("contact--form--email--error").style.display='block';
        return false;
    }
    else if(name=="") {
        document.getElementById("contact--form--name--error").style.display='block';
        return false;
    }
}
```

The main problem here is that the javascript code is applied correctly for the email, but in the else if for the name it does not apply.

However, if I delete the email and change it by name it works correctly, I can't make it apply for both (I also want to apply it to the input with name info which would be adding another else if)

If you find any improvement in the javascript code, I appreciate the information, I am a student who has never studied javascript and has been learning several languages ​​in a self-taught way for some time.

Comment: `email.trim();` doesn’t do anything; you’re not using its result. Just do `let email = document.getElementById('email').value.trim();`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian :D, already changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//if is empty email or name good luck

if(!email||!name){
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
return true;
```

to the end of the function.

```js
function contactFormEmpty() {
  let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  email.trim();
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  name.trim();
  if (email == "") {
    document.getElementById("contact--form--email--error").style.display =
      "block";
    return false;
  } else if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById("contact--form--name--error").style.display =
      "block";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.contact--form--error {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/contact.php" method="POST" id="contact--form" onsubmit="return contactFormEmpty()" name="contact--form"></form>
    <input class="form--input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="CORREO ELECTRONICO"><br>
    <p id="contact--form--email--error" class="contact--form--error">Error: no se ha entrado ningun correo</p>
   
    <input class="form--input" type="text" name="nombre" id="name" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
    <p id="contact--form--name--error" class="contact--form--error">Error: no se ha entrado ningun nombre</p>
   
    <input class="form--input" type="text" name="surrname" id="surrname" placeholder="APELLIDO"><br>
   
    <input class="form--input form--problem--info" type="text" name="info" id="info" placeholder="DESCRIBE TU PROBLEMA"><br>
    <p id="contact--form--info--error" class="contact--form--error">Error: no se ha descrito el problema.</p>
   
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR INFORMACIÓN" form="contact--form">
   
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is not with checking the 'name' field, it is what happens after. Let's say you did not enter the name, an error message will appear and the function will return false, but when you enter the name, the error message will not disappear, and the function will not return true, then you think the function is not checking the name!

Comment: I have already tried this option, it does not modify the result, have you tried the code?

Comment: I updated the comment so you can try it here!